# Running spark from an application

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Use case: I have a java application(let's say a server) that contains some data in memory(). From that application, I want to run a spark ML pipeline with the data from the application.

What options do I have?
I've already considered creating a jar with ML pipeline and java interface and using [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher) to run this pipeline. However, I don't see any possibility to inexpensively transfer the in-memory data to the jar.

As performance is important in my case, writing the data to a file is not desired.

p.s. The pipeline is meant to run in a local(or standalone) mode.

Comment: Something to think about - If you're going to run Spark in local mode, why use Spark at all? Especially when handling local objects is already a problem?

Comment: @user6910411 Unfortunately, among java ml libraries only spark's mllib has a desired ml functionality.

Comment: And what functionality would that be?

Comment: @user6910411 feature importance calculation in decision tree algorithm

Comment: You might take a look at [JeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq). The nice thing about using 0mq is it gives you the option to expand your subscriber(s) should you get additional resources for your project.

Comment: It doesn't sound right. I am pretty sure that at least H20 and RapidMiner do, you could XGBoost for similar things, run R on JVM with Renjin, and computing importance metrics, is not a rocket science anyway, so you could compute your own. And I am pretty sure there are tools, I am not aware of (don't really use Java).

Comment: @user6910411 h20 does not have a simple decision tree. Yeah, you right, but the requirements were to use decision tree as it performs faster. I am also not java user, but I haven't come across any library in java that can do that. However, it seems like RapidMiner has it as well as feature importance calculation. I will take a closer look at that. Thank you!

Comment: Still, as the implementation in Spark is already there, I would like to know the answer to my original question.

Comment: You know, overhead of running local Spark job for each invocation will be much higher than cost of serializing object that local mode can actually handle.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "cost of serializing object that local mode can actually handle"? 

Will it not be dependent on the in-memory object size?